# Multiple group by for dataset query

Tags: birt

I am currently working on report generation using BIRT Tool. consider the table below,

```
TaskId                  Status               SLAMiss
----------------------------------------------------------
   1                    Completed              Yes
   2                    In Progress            No
   3                    Completed              No
```

I need to create a table which shows the count of **Completed** ,**In progress** tasks along with the count **SLA missed** tasks like below,

```
Tasks Completed     Tasks InProgress      SLA Adherence           SLA Miss
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
      2                   1                    2                      1
```

Now i need to create the dataset using sql query. For the first two columns i have to group by **'Status'**. And for the last two columns i have to group by **'SLA Miss'**. So,

```
1.Is it possible to achieve this using a single dataset? 
2.If yes what will be the sql query for the dataset?
3.If not, I can create 4 dataset's for each column and apply that to the table.
  Will that be a good idea?
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiset way to do this is use computed columns. You would use some JavaScript like the following in a new colum named "CompletedCount" as Interger.  Then when you build your report you sum the values with an "Aggregation" item from the palette.

```
if (row["Status"] == "Completed" )
{
"1"
 }else{
"0"}
```